# Create and read UTF-8 folders java

Tags: java, file-io, utf-8

How can I create and read folders in `Java` when using UTF-8 characters?
Currently the 'ä'-character in my folder named "strängePath" are getting replaced with '?'. Any hints on where to find a solution?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFilePath {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create folder and file: [Project]/strängePath/tmp.txt
        String homePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String dirPath = createDirectory("strängePath", homePath);
        String path = createFile("tmp.txt", dirPath);

        // Try to read the created "tmp.txt" file
        try {
            new FileInputStream(path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String createDirectory(String dirName, String path) {
        String dirPath = path + "/" + dirName;
        File file = new File(dirPath);
        System.out.println("Created folder: " + dirPath + " -> " + file.mkdir());
        return dirPath;
    }

    private static String createFile(String fileName, String path) {
        String filePath = path + "/" + fileName;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try {
            System.out.println("Created file: " + filePath + " -> " + file.createNewFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenver you are creating a String, use new String("content","UTF-8");

Comment: @Hirak There is no such constructor.

Comment: Have you checked what was created on disk? It's possible your `System.out` output looks wrong if your console isn't UTF-8 friendly.

Comment: use `System.getProperty("file.separator")` instead of `/` in file path.

Comment: My bad, use new String("content".getBytes(), charsetName). Also, the editor console output also needs to have UTF-8 encoding if you are printing the names

Comment: @Braj Or File file = new File(new File(path),filename);

Comment: @Duncan The System.out looks correct but the result on disk is replacing the special characters with '?'

Comment: @Hirak I still don't think that code will achieve anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused by the encoding of the source file: it is different from the encoding of the system. If your file is saved using UTF-8 but you are in Windows, the "hardcoded" text will be UTF-8 but Windows does not use that.